# System.Text.Json.JsonElement.GetString fails for numeric values

Tags: c#, system.text.json

Consider these two JSONs:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 40
}
```

and

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "40"
}
```

The only difference is that in one, `40` is a number, in the other it's a string.

I need to parse these JSONs using `System.Text.Json` and my code fails:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string.

I deserialize the JSON and then use `JsonElement.GetString()` to get the values.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you use `ToString`? Clearly, `40` is *not* a string.

Comment: When you want to deserialize it to that object, please show the destination object here that you have defined.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I have a list of JSON strings. Let's say more than 100 thousand items. And in some of them it's a number, in some of them it's string.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, there is no destination object. I deserialize into dictionary, or into `JsonElement`.

Comment: If your using newton soft it's sensitive, but in .net core new standard libraries I found that there were no sensivity. Would you say which Json lib you have imported?

Comment: @Hamed_gibago as I have mentioned in the question, I'm using `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: use object or dynamic as type for the problematic element

Comment: @J.Salas, there is no `GetObject` method on `JsonElement`. I searched by I didn't find.

Comment: Why don't you use [JsonElement's ValueKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=net-6.0) to determine the type before you call GetString or any other GetXYZ method?

Comment: @PeterCsala, that worked. Thank you. But I wish working with JSON was easier in this stupid new library.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `JsonElement` then you can use its [`ValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=net-6.0) property to determine the type of the json which it represents.

So, for instance if you have parsed a `JsonDocument` and you retrieve its `RootElement` then that `JsonElement`'s `ValueKind` can be either `Array` or `Object`.

If you have a `JsonElement` by calling the `GetProperty` then the returned `JsonElement`'s `ValueKind` can be [any of the predefined values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonvaluekind?view=net-6.0).

---

In your particular example you can use the `ValueKind` to determine which `GetXYZ` method should be called based on the fetched property's data type.

```
string input1 = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 40}";
string input2 = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": \"40\"}";

foreach (var input in new[] { input1, input2 })
{
    var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(input);
    var age = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("age");
    switch (age.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Number:
        {
            var value = age.GetInt32();
            Console.WriteLine($"{value} as a number");
            break;
        }
        case JsonValueKind.String:
        {
            var value = age.GetString();
            Console.WriteLine($"{value} as a text");
            break;
        }
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("unknown type");
            break;
    }
}
```

---

The above code is a bit fragile, since I've picked `GetInt32` if the `ValueKind` is `Number`.
But if you don't know upfront the number's data type then you should use the `TryGetXYZ` methods to try to fetch numbers in a safe way.

```
string input1 = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 40}";
string input2 = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": \"40\"}";
string input3 = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 40.0}";

foreach (var input in new[] { input1, input2, input3 })
{
    var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(input);
    var age = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("age");
    switch (age.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Number:
            {
                if(age.TryGetInt32(out var integralNumber))
                    Console.WriteLine($"{integralNumber} as an integral number");
                else if (age.TryGetDouble(out var floatingNumber))
                    Console.WriteLine($"{floatingNumber} as a floating number");
                break;
            }
        case JsonValueKind.String:
            {
                var value = age.GetString();
                Console.WriteLine($"{value} as a text");
                break;
            }
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("unknown type");
            break;
    }
}
```